# DateTime.Now error in mono under Raspbian on Raspberry Pi

Tags: mono, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I DateTime.Now returns '734997/00/0001 11:13:07'.
How to solve this problem?

P.S. I know that this error is not under '[Soft-float Debian "wheezy"](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads)', but the SD card with this OS did not want to boot :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Workaround is to avoid all Math.* that works with floating point.
Since DateTime.ToString() use it it is broken too.

You can still use DateTime.Now.Year/Month/Day... which return the correct values.